# QuickSight Paginated Report Publish to Email Endpoints

Tags: sharepoint-2010, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I have a SharePoint Email endpoint that I need to publish my QuickSight Paginated Report to, as an email with a PDF attachment. I'm unable to enlist the endpoint (exchange-xxx@company.com) as a recipient in the schedule, because I'm unable to grant it any permissions.

As a workaround, for now, I have resorted to using a server-side Outlook rule to forward the email publish being sent to me, to SharePoint.

Any insights/better workarounds are appreciated too!